# Origine de "L'urgent est fait, l'impossible est en cours, pour les miracles, prévoir un délai"

Tags: expressions, origine-ou-raison

Il existe plusieures variantes de l'expression:

> L'urgent est fait, l'impossible est en cours, pour les miracles, prévoir un délai

sur le net, mais j'aimerais savoir son origine.

J'ai cherché un peu sur internet, mais je n'ai rien pu trouver, si ce n'est une [question similaire](https://www.englishforums.com/English/ImpossibleImmediatelyMiraclesLittle-Longer/vmczx/post.htm) sur un autre site pour une variante anglophone de l'expression: *The Impossible We Do Immediately, Miracles Take A Little Longer*.

Parmi les réponses sur ce site, il y a de possibles origines parmi des militaires de la seconde guerre mondiale, d'autres parlent d'autres généraux de la première guerre mondiale ! Enfin cette [page](http://www.bartleby.com/73/1183.html) indique

> This echoes a remark attributed to Charles-Alexandre de Calonne, Louis XVI’s minister of finance. Marie Antoinette asked him something in a tone that brooked no refusal, adding that perhaps it would be difficult. He replied, “If it is only difficult, it is done; if it is impossible, we shall see.”—J. F. Michaud, Biographie Universelle, vol. 6, p. 427.

Que l'on pourrait traduire par

> *Ceci renvoie à une remarque attribuée à Charles-Alexandre de Calonne, ministre des finances de Louis XVI. Marie Antoinette lui a demandé quelque chose dans un ton qui ne souffrait pas de refus, tout en acceptant sa possible difficulté. Il répondit, "Madame, si c’est possible, c’est fait ; impossible, cela se fera."* (traduction libre, citation traduite [ici](https://www.histoire-en-citations.fr/citations/calonne-madame-si-c-est-possible-c-est-fait))

Pourriez-vous m'éclairer d'où vient cette expression ?

Comment: J'ai trouvé une vieille affiche qui utilise cette expression, mais plus récente que CA de Calonne. Ca me fait penser à "Je fais des prodiges, pas des miracles"... Il y a tellement de variations, je ne pense pas qu'on puisse remonter à une "première origine".

Comment: Commentaire à part: Pouvez-vous mettre la citation en Francais aussi (“If it is only difficult, it is done; if it is impossible, we shall see.”) ? Les mots changement parfois lors de la traduction, et je suppose que la citation a été dite en francais.

Comment: @Nathan, je peux traduire la phrase, mais comme le site en question est en anglais, et tente de donner une origine à la version anglaise... je ne peux être sûr des mots exacts employé (ou reportés) par CA de Calonne.

Comment: À propos de la traduction libre, l’original, ainsi que le pressentait @Nathan, semble différent de la citation anglaise: [Madame, si c’est possible, c’est fait ; impossible, cela se fera.](https://www.histoire-en-citations.fr/citations/calonne-madame-si-c-est-possible-c-est-fait).

Comment: @Feelew, j'ai changé ma traduction pour mettre la version du site en question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Au cours des dernières années, la phrase

> L’impossible recule toujours quand on marche vers lui.

est devenue la devise de la compagnie Altrad. Cette citation est vraisemblablement anonyme, mais elle est le plus souvent attribuée, probablement à tort, au grand Antoine de Saint-Exupéry (1900-1944). Les recherches en ligne semblent indiquer qu’elle soit bien plus récente que Saint-Exupéry, mais plus ancienne que son adoption par Altrad. Au hasard, parce que ce n’est pas critique ici, disons quelque part au tournant du millénaire.

Il semble que le filon de déclarer possible l’impossible en soit un bon, et tout un chacun semble pouvoir avec succès attacher une signature illustre à sa propre version de la chose.

Ainsi se trouve assez universellement attribuée, mais de nouveau de manière probablement apocryphe, au très renommé écrivain américain Mark Twain (1835-1910), cette citation qui nous indique que la frontière de l’impossible pourrait souvent être davantage psychologique que réelle :

> They did not know it was impossible, so they did it!
>       *(Ils ne savaient pas que c’était impossible, alors ils l’ont fait !)*

En continuant à remonter le temps, presque contemporain avec la citation de Calonne mentionnée dans la question, on retrouve, attribuée à Napoléon (1769-1821), cette phrase désormais proverbiale :

> [Impossible n’est pas français.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_n%27est_pas_fran%C3%A7ais)

Phrase dont on pourra retrouver des sources contemporaines attestant au moins quelque chose d’assez approché, par exemple dans les [Souvenirs du duc de Vicence](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k29216g/f18.double.r=souvenirs%20du%20duc%20de%20vicence), dont on peut constater qu’ils mentionnent, en page 13 du tome 1 (1837) :

> L’Empereur ne m’a paru, dans aucune circonstance, au-dessous de sa gigantesque position. Son génie, sa capacité, ses immenses moyens intellectuels dominaient les faits prodigieux de son règne ; et lorsqu’il disait que le mot *impossible* n’était pas français, c’est qu’en effet il ne le comprenait pas. Il sentait en lui de quoi résoudre les problèmes les plus abstraits, de quoi vaincre toutes les impossibilités ; il s’élançait, en jouant, dans les plus hautes régions de l’intelligence humaine.

Puis on retrouve cette fameuse citation de Charles-Alexandre de Calonne, ministre des Finances sous Louis XVI, répondant en 1784 à une requête de Marie-Antoinette :

> [Madame, si c’est possible, c’est fait ; impossible, cela se fera.](https://www.histoire-en-citations.fr/citations/calonne-madame-si-c-est-possible-c-est-fait)

Le site en lien déclare que ces propos sont rapportés par Alexis de Tocqueville dans son essai *L’Ancien Régime et la Révolution (1856)*. Une recherche plus poussée pour retrouver le morceau dans la source citée, chez M. de Tocqueville, m’a cependant laissé [les mains vides](http://classiques.uqac.ca/classiques/De_tocqueville_alexis/ancien_regime/Ancien_regime.pdf)... Serait-ce à nouveau une citation faussement attribuée ? Je l’ai cru un moment, mais en cherchant davantage, j’ai été mis sur la piste de la *Biographie ancienne et moderne* (en 45 tomes), publiée en 1812, où l’on retrouve la citation telle quelle à l’article *Calonne* ([tome 6, p. 567](https://books.google.ca/books?id=za4FAAAAQAAJ&q=%22n%27est+que+difficile+c%27est+fait+si+cela+est+impossible+nous+verrons%22&pg=PA567&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22n'est%20que%20difficile%20c'est%20fait%20si%20cela%20est%20impossible%20nous%20verrons%22&f=false), voir aussi [une édition ultérieure, 1843, en page 427](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k516466/f432.item.zoom)). Les deux éditions précèdent l’essai de Tocqueville et semblent donc mieux indiquées pour être la source de la citation.

<sup>*En 1812, néanmoins, ces propos rapportés dataient déjà de 30 ans, ce qui paraît suffisant pour que l’on puisse soupçonner une source écrite antérieure, que je n’ai pas retrouvée, ou une passation orale au cours de la période intermédiaire, qui pourrait avoir embelli les paroles, voire une pure invention, heureuse il est vrai, placée dans un passé assez lointain pour ne plus être investigué correctement, mais assez récent pour que l’on puisse présumer des sources encore existantes.*</sup>

Pourrait-on encore remonter dans le temps et trouver une inspiration encore plus ancienne de l’impossible rendu possible ? Je me permets d’aller un pas plus loin que Calonne, mais ça nous fera un bond de presque 350 ans dans le temps...

Un homme du XVe siècle, nommé [Jacques Cœur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_C%C5%93ur) (ca. 1395 ou 1400—1456), né roturier et anobli en 1441, choisit une devise demeurée célèbre, jeu de mots sur son nom et affirmation déjà que l’impossible est un simple point de vue, relatif et franchissable :

> A vaillans cuers riens impossible. *(À cœur vaillant, rien d’impossible.)*

---

#### Ajout ultérieur

Lisant récemment *« Five Ways to Forgiveness »* de l’écrivaine américaine Ursula K. Le Guin, j’ai été mis en contact avec une citation encore plus ancienne du philosophe chrétien Tertullian (ca. 155—ca. 240) :

> [*Certum est quia impossibile est*](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Certum_est_quia_impossibile_est)

En contexte dans le texte de l’auteur :

> Crucifixus est dei filius; non pudet, quia pudendum est.
>   Et mortuus est dei filius; credibile prorsus est, quia ineptum est.
>   Et sepultus resurrexit; **certum est, quia impossibile.**
>
> Le fils de Dieu crucifié : je n’en suis pas honteux, car c’est honteux.
>   Le fils de Dieu mort : c’est immédiatement crédible, car c’est inepte.
>   Ressuscité des morts : c’est certain, car c’est impossible.
>      <sub>– traduction personnelle avec l’aide de la traduction anglaise d’Ernest Evans</sub>

La signification de la citation est plutôt différente de celle présentée dans la question : le philosophe admet la résurrection comme vraie, car le simple fait que les gens y ont cru suffit à la valider, une vaste communauté ne pouvant vraiment croire à une chose si impossible que si elle est en effet survenue.

Est malgré tout à nouveau émise cette idée de l’impossible prenant pied dans la réalité.

En 1916, John Moffat a rapproché cet argument d’un élément de la Rhétorique d’[Aristote](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristote) ([Livre 2, 23.22](http://remacle.org/bloodwolf/philosophes/Aristote/rheto2.htm#XXIII)) :

> **XXII.** Un autre lieu se tire des faits qui semblent bien arriver, mais qui sont cependant incroyables en ce sens qu’ils sembleraient impossibles, s’ils n’existaient réellement ou s’ils n’étaient à la veille de se produire, et aussi parce qu’ils arrivent plutôt (que d’autres). En effet, on n’a d’opinion que sur un fait existant, ou sur un fait vraisemblable. Par conséquent, si la chose est à la fois incroyable et invraisemblable, il faut nécessairement qu’elle soit réelle ; car ce n’est pas comme vraisemblable ou probable qu’elle pourrait paraître telle. Exemple : Androclès de Pitthée parlant contre les lois, comme on lui répondait par des rumeurs tumultueuse : « Les lois, dit-il, ont besoin d’une autre loi qui les corrige, car les poissons ont besoin de sel, et cependant il n’est pas vraisemblable, ni probable que, vivant dans l’eau salée, ils aient besoin de sel, et les olives, d’huile, et cependant, il est incroyable que ce qui sert à faire l’huile ait besoin d’huile. »

Aristote ayant vécu au IV<sup>e</sup> siècle avant notre ère, il apparaît que la réflexion sur la possibilité concrète de l’irréel dans la réalité soit plurimillénaire. Elle a pris différentes formes au cours des âges, mais la filiation, au moins partielle, me semble probable.

Comment: Dans la veine de la barrière psychologique, il y a Sénèque: _Non quia difficilia sunt non audemus, sed quia non audemus difficilia sunt_: Ce n'est pas parce que c'est difficile que nous n'osons pas, mais parce que nous n'osons pas que c'est difficile.